# How to get the right values for mouse hold-and-drag boxing

Tags: python, selection, pygame

I'm trying to implement drawing boxes in a program, like when you hold a mouse button and there is a rectangle when you move the mouse around. Trying to do it with a pygame rect object and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
def mouseDown(self, button, pos):
    if button == 1:
        self.pressing = True
        self.start = pos

def mouseUp(self, button, pos):
    if button == 1:
        self.pressing = False

def mouseMotion(self, buttons, pos):
    if self.pressing == True:
        width = abs(self.start[0] - pos[0])
        height = abs(self.start[1] - pos[1])
        self.box = pygame.Rect(self.start, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), self.box, 1)
```

So pos is the coordinates of the click, with (0,0) being top left corner. I tried to use abs to get the size by comparing how far the mouse has moved, but abs only returns positive values, and therefor it doesn't work.

How can we change this to make box selection possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Calums very helpful answer as a stepping stone, I came up with this solution:

```
def mouseMotion(self, buttons, pos, rel):

    if self.pressing == True:
        diffx = self.start[0] - pos[0]
        diffy = self.start[1] - pos[1]            
        width = abs(self.start[0] - pos[0])
        height = abs(self.start[1] - pos[1])
        if diffx > 0 and diffy > 0:
            width = (width - (width * 2))
            height = (height - (height * 2))
        elif diffx > 0 and diffy <= 0:
            width = (width - (width * 2))
        elif diffx <= 0 and diffy > 0:
            height = (height - (height * 2))
        elif diffx < 0 and diffy < 0:
            pass

        dimensions = (width, height)
        self.box = pygame.Rect(self.start, dimensions)

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), self.box, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
def mouseMotion(self, buttons, pos):
    if self.pressing == True:
        diffx = self.start[0] - pos[0]
        diffy = self.start[1] - pos[1]
        width = abs(self.start[0] - pos[0])
        height = abs(self.start[1] - pos[1])
        if diffx >= 0:
            if diffy >= 0:
                self.box = pygame.Rect(self.start, width, height)
            else:
                self.box = pygame.Rect(self.start[0],pos[1], width, height)
        else:
            if diffy >= 0:
                self.box = pygame.Rect(pos[0],self.start[1], width, height)
            else:
                self.box = pygame.Rect(pos, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), self.box, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case is use the pygame mouse function. The module you could use is `pygame.mouse.get_rel` run that when you first click on the "Drawing area" and again when the mouse button is raised, the second call of that code will give you the distance between the two points, and using some pygame.mouse.get_pos 's you could find the start and end points of the rectangle, and simply draw them with pygame. I hope you understand this, i'll see if i can a code example.